# Си.Почему не записывается в память размерность матрицы из текстового файла?И как это осуществить?

Tags: c, файлы, память, матрицы, текст

В той программе, где я не использовал функцию, а писал всё в теле программы, проблем не было.Всё считало верно.И промежуточный вывод `printf("%d",c1); printf("%d",r2);` выводил верные значения.Матрицы считываются с файла отлично и выводятся на экран тоже, но я их не могу перемножить, потому что c1 и r2(число строк в первой матрице и число столбцов во второй) нет в памяти программы, т.к. выводятся нули.Как их "оставить" в памяти ?!Помогите пожалуйста :(

UPD:
Сейчас вообще выводит с1, что это 1, а r2 это -1 (хотя это не так!)
Ничего не понимаю..

```
void openprint (int **x, int n, int m){
        int j , i,k;
    FILE *f;
    char name [25];
    printf ("enter the name of the file");
    scanf ("%s", name);
    if((f=fopen(name,"r"))==NULL){
        printf ("file not found");
        system ("PAUSE");
        
        }
    
    fscanf (f,"%d%d",&n,&m) ;
    
    x=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    x[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*m);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     for(j=0;j<m;j++)
     fscanf(f,"%d", &x[i][j]);
    fclose(f);
    printf(" matrix:\n") ;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
         printf ("%3d", x[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int **A, r1,c1; 
    int **B, r2,c2; 
    int **C;
    int i , j,k;
    openprint( A,r1,c1);
    openprint( B,r2,c2);
printf("%d",c1);    
printf("%d",r2) ;
if (c1 != r2) {
printf("Error! cannot be multiplyed.\n");
}

else{
    C=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*r1);
for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
C[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*c2);} 
   for ( i = 0; i < r1; ++i) {
      for (j = 0; j < c2; ++j) {
        C[i][j] = 0;
         for ( k = 0; k < c1; ++k) {
            C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            
         }
      }
   }

printf("\n the result of multiplying\n");
for (i = 0; i < r1; i++)
{
for (j = 0; j < c2; j++)
printf("%3d ", C[i][j]);
printf("\n");
}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Параметры `n` и `m` у функции `void openprint (int **x, int n, int m)` при таком способе передачи (по значению) по сути являются локальными для нее. Как не изменяйте их внутри функции, "снаружи" они (т.е. уже реальные параметры) никак не изменятся. Если хотите, чтобы измененные параметры внутри функции были так же изменены и "снаружи", передавайте указатели на них (т.е. нужно изменить и заголовок функции, и обращение к этим переменным внутри функции, и вызов функции).

Comment: @Vladimir, скажите пожалуйста, как это и где записать?Я просто чайник, извиняйте :''')

Comment: @Vladimir я не знаю, где проставить эти *, чтобы оно работало корректно, путаюсь в них..Кучи ошибок в компиляторе :(

Comment: Во-первых, у Вас там не хватает закрывающей фигурной скобки в `main()`. Во-вторых, с Вашими матрицами будет та же история, что и с параметрами `n` и `m` - Вы не сможете получить доступ к этим матрицам снаружи функции таким способом.  В-третьих, у Вас будет утечка памяти: раз уж используете динамическую память, то не забывайте ее освобождать.

Comment: Я бы предложил вместо передачи параметра `int **x` возвращать его из функции. Так будет проще все исправить (альтернатива - это использовать вместо него `int ***x`.

Comment: @ Vladimir Фигурную скобку уже давно вернул, случайно стёр :) Освобождение памяти добавил. Так.int ***x в заголовке прописал.Прописал вызов ф-ции , если это так делается.. openprint( &A,&r1,&c1); Но всё равно возвращает огромное значение , вместо 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На скорую руку, примерно так. Я код не проверял пока, чтобы быстрее.

```
void openprint (int **x, int *n, int *m){
int j , i,k;
FILE *f;
char name [25];
printf ("enter the name of the file");
scanf ("%s", name);
if((f=fopen(name,"r"))==NULL){
    printf ("file not found");
    system ("PAUSE");
    
    }

fscanf (f,"%d%d", n, m) ;

x=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*   *n);
for(i=0;i< *n;i++)
x[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*  *m);
for(i=0;i< *n;i++)
 for(j=0;j< *m;j++)
 fscanf(f,"%d", &x[i][j]);
fclose(f);
printf(" matrix:\n") ;
for(i=0;i< *n;i++){
    for(j=0;j< *m;j++)
     printf ("%3d", x[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

И потом вызов этой функции соответственно должен быть такой:

```
openprint( A, &r1, &c1);
```

**UPD:**
В дополнение к моим комментариям, вот исправленный вариант, который я предлагаю (т.е. чтобы матрицу возвращали из функции, а не передавали её как параметр). При этом. я здесь не исправил утечку памяти - с этим Вы сами справитесь или тоже надо показать?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ** openprint (int *n, int *m)
    {
        int j , i;
        FILE *f;
        char name [25];
        printf ("enter the name of the file");
        scanf ("%s", name);
        if((f = fopen(name, "r")) == NULL)
        {
            printf ("file not found");
            system ("PAUSE");

        }

        fscanf (f, "%d%d", n, m) ;

        int **x = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) *   *n);
        for(i = 0; i < *n; i++)
            x[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) *  *m);
        for(i = 0; i < *n; i++)
            for(j = 0; j < *m; j++)
                fscanf(f, "%d", &x[i][j]);
        fclose(f);
        printf(" matrix:\n") ;
        for(i = 0; i < *n; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < *m; j++)
                printf ("%3d", x[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        
        return x;
    }


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int **A, r1, c1;
    int **B, r2, c2;
    int **C;
    int i , j, k;
//  openprint( A, &r1, &c1);
    A = openprint(&r1, &c1);
//  openprint( B, &r2, &c2);
    B = openprint(&r2, &c2);
    printf("%d", c1);
    printf("%d", r2) ;
    if (c1 != r2)
    {
        printf("Error! cannot be multiplyed.\n");
    }

    else
    {
        C = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*r1);
        for(i = 0; i < r1; i++)
        {
            C[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * c2);
        }
        for ( i = 0; i < r1; ++i)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < c2; ++j)
            {
                C[i][j] = 0;
                for ( k = 0; k < c1; ++k)
                {
                    C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];

                }
            }
        }

        printf("\n the result of multiplying\n");
        for (i = 0; i < r1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < c2; j++)
                printf("%3d ", C[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо!Теперь верно выводит r1 и c2 в промежуточном выводе
printf("%d",c1); printf("%d",r2);
Но вот почему то после else , где идет перемножение матриц программа не хочет работать и возвращает только огромное значение....

Comment: @Yuikus, я обновил ответ, во второй части привел всю программу целиком. Она все еще не совсем корректна, но перемножить матрицы уже должна (если там у Вас все верно)

Comment: спасибо огромное!!! Теперь перемножает :)  
Считает - уже замечательно, остальное, надеюсь, подправлю сам!Спасибо еще раз за помощь